# GWT Cookies, returning null when  setting during an rpc

Tags: java, gwt, cookies

I am becoming almost mad with the GWT Cookies,

in one of my application I set the cookie in an RPC success, but I am trying to retrieve it in another place of my application, it returns null.

I know that when setting a variable in an rpc sucess,if we try to access it elsewhere it result null, so how can i set a cookie an rpc so that it does not returns null??

Edit:-
I am doing something like this:

I do in Main.java

```
RPC.getUserDetails(new AsyncCallback <String>())
{
  public void onSuccess(String result)
  {
      Cookies.set("UserDetails",result);
  }
}
```

Now in another file.java, when i do `Cookies.get("UserDetails")`, I get null

Comment: It would be useful if you provided the code you are using.

Comment: @Piotr, i edited the post, I am doing an RPC and within the rpc, the call is being made

Comment: Hm, this should work. Have you checked if `result` parameter isn't `null` when `onSuccess` method is invoked? Maybe this is the case.

Comment: @Piotr, have u checked it. if u do something like 1.Initialise a string to null 2. Assign the string during an rpc 3. outside the rpc, try window.alert(InitialisedString), this would return null, for string, it ok, but for cookies this should have been different because it's a shared variable

Comment: @Noor, I was thinking about such situation: (1) you invoke `getUserDetails` service from your client code; (2) your server code processes the request and returns `null` as the result of `getUserDetails` method; (3) you get the response from the server and `onSuccess` method is invoked in your client code. If this happens then the value of `result` in `onSuccess` method will be null and so the value of `UserDetails` cookie also will be set to null. Consequently all subsequent calls to `Cookies.get("UserDetails")` will return null (as this is the actual value of the cookie).

Comment: @Piotr, I am checking the result value when getting it from the rpc, it is not null

Comment: Try calling Cookies.getCookie("UserDetails") immediately after setting it. I'm unsure what Cookies class you're using that has a get method.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after setting expiration time I was able to retrieve it:

```
Date now = new Date();
long week = now.getTime();
week = week + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
Cookies.setCookie("UserDetails", result, week);
```

Also make sure that you are setting **none secure** cookie and are retrieving **none secure** cookie. Make sure by checking the browser if the cookie file exists. And check the content of the file. If you have problems after this post the content of the cookie file here.

Comment: Any idea regarding [this very similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685532/why-is-my-cookie-always-null)?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it also this way:

```
Date expires = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 3600 * 24));
String categoriesCookieJson = asJson(allCategories);
System.out.println("inserting cat cookie lenth : " + categoriesCookieJson.toCharArray().length + " : " + categoriesCookieJson);
Cookies.setCookie(VU_ME_CATEGORIES_CACHE, categoriesCookieJson, expires);

String categoriesJsonCookieCache = Cookies.getCookie(VU_ME_CATEGORIES_CACHE);
System.out.println("cookie in chache " + categoriesJsonCookieCache);
```

it returns `null` and there's no cookie file entry (looking in ff firebug)

```
inserting cat cookie lenth : 8303 : {"categories":[{"id":"71","name":"Immoblier","children":[{"id":"76","parentKey":"71","name":"Terrain....
```

cookie in chache null

Ok!!! so it seams it's related to the size of my cookie content:

```
inserting cat cookie length : 8303
```

I will have to split the data

Comment: *it returns null* - i think it is the problem faced by OP.