# Why is my cookie always null?

Tags: gwt

I don't get this. An hour ago it worked and all of a sudden I can't get back the cookie I just set. Under Chrome I can see that the cookie is actually there but if I try to get it back it's `null`:

```java
private void setLoggedInCookie(String sessionId) {
    String domain = this.getDomain();

    Cookies.setCookie(ApiParameters.LOGIN_COOKIE, sessionId, expires, domain, "/", true);
    String cookie = Cookies.getCookie(ApiParameters.LOGIN_COOKIE);

    // Getting NOTHING from this ..
    for (String string : Cookies.getCookieNames()) {
        LOGGER.info("Cookie name: " + string);
    }

    if(cookie == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cookie is 'null'.");
    }
}

private String getDomain() {
    LOGGER.fine("Host name: " + Window.Location.getHostName());
    String domain = Window.Location.getHostName().replaceAll(".*//", "").replaceAll("/", "").replaceAll(":.*", "");
    return "localhost".equalsIgnoreCase(domain) ? "localhost" : domain;
}
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass domain name "null". Browsers allow access only to cookies associated with the current page's domain. Since you are trying to access it from a page which is not "null", you can't get it.

Also, make sure you are trying to access it using SSL, since you set "secure" parameter to true.

Comment: It's not working even if I set it to `localhost`. Like in my question stated: I can see the cookie is there in Chrome/Firefox settings but I don't get it back from `Cookies.getCookie()`.

Comment: Make sure you are trying to access it using SSL, since you set it to true. NB: You can always set a cookie - it has no impact on your ability to get it.

Comment: The mistake was setting it to secure. I changed it from `false` to `true` and didn't know that this means I'd have to access it using SSL! Setting the domain does not seem to be a problem though - at least not for retrieving it back. Thank you!